# C++ Ogre Runtime error 'Assertion failed'

Tags: c++, runtime-error, assert, ogre

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...ments\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OgreTest\Debug\OgreTest.exe
>   File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
>   Line: 1424
>
> Expression: _pFirstBlock == pHead
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion
>   failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

That's what I got when I try to execute my Ogre application. Source is a total copy of Ogre Tutorial Framework. I found ridiculously much exceptions from Ogre.log. It seems like that all of the errors came from `OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp` and `OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp`. Some of the first ones coming next. I couldn't paste em all, because there's about 1000 lines of that crap.

```
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: High-level program Ogre/DualQuaternionHardwareSkinningTwoWeightsCg encountered an error during loading and is thus not supported.
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in DualQuaternion.program(14): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: High-level program Ogre/DualQuaternionHardwareSkinningTwoWeightsTwoPhaseCg encountered an error during loading and is thus not supported.
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource DualQuaternion.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in DualQuaternion.program(28): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: Parsing script Examples.program
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource Example_Basic.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: High-level program Ogre/BasicVertexPrograms/AmbientOneTextureCg encountered an error during loading and is thus not supported.
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource Example_Basic.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in Examples.program(16): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in Examples.program(17): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource Example_Basic.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: High-level program Ogre/HardwareSkinningFourWeights encountered an error during loading and is thus not supported.
OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource Example_Basic.cg in resource group Popular or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in Examples.program(314): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in Examples.program(315): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
17:55:32: Compiler error: invalid parameters in Examples.program(316): setting of constant failed
17:55:32: OGRE EXCEPTION(2:InvalidParametersException): Named constants have not been initialised, perhaps a compile error. in GpuProgramParameters::_findNamedConstantDefinition at ..\..\..\..\OgreMain\src\OgreGpuProgramParams.cpp (line 1709)
```

Notice, that those errors came only when using OpenGL or D3D9 rendersystems. When using D3D11, runtime error is different:

> OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Attemped to render to a D3D11
>   device without both vertex and fragment shaders there is no fixed
>   pipeline in d3d11 - use the RTSS or write custom shaders. in
>   D3D11RenderSystem::_render at
>   ..........\RenderSystems\Direct3D11\src\OgreD3D11RenderSystem.cpp
>   (line 2496)

I can paste even more info is it's necessary. Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: Hard for us to guess without knowing the coding lines that caused the issue. What does the debugger tell you regarding the crash? Did you pay attention to Ogre versions?

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier Crash comes from `mRoot->startRendering()`. My Ogre version is 1.9.0.

Comment: I have the same issue as above but using VS 2015 :(

Answer (score 0):

This error usually appears if you are mixing release and debug builds. Most likely your application was built in release mode while you are trying to use debug build DLLs in this case of Ogre.

You can use a tool such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check what DLLs exactly are loaded during your application's run.

Another reason could that your Ogre DLLs where generated by a different IDE/compiler version than your actual application is. This will often make them binary-incompatible resulting in crashes. This can happen due to different versions of the standard library and associated dynamic allocation issues. The same is possible if you build the Ogre libraries as 'static', but use dynamic dependencies (e.g. OIS, plugins, etc.).

Regarding the errors in the log: You seem to be missing some media files (e. g. shaders) which cause those log entries.

Regarding D3D11: With that version Microsoft removed the FFP (fixed-function pipeline). So everything is now shader based which means that you either have to write/provide these on your own or use Ogre's integrated shader generator ([RTTS](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=RT%20Shader%20System)).

Comment: I checked my exe with the tool you recommeded, and it said that my program uses following dlls: OgreMain_d.dll, OgreOverlay_d.dll, OIS_d.dll, user32.dll, MSVCP120D.dll, boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll, MSVCR120D.dll and kernel32.dll. So all of them are debug dlls (aren't they?). Yes, my program is a debug build.

Comment: @user3725053 Added a note regarding compiler versions.